# Lebesgue-Stiletjes measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $F$ be a two variable continous function that satisfy
\begin{equation}
F(x_1,y) \leq F(x_2,y) \text{ for } x_1\leq x_2,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
F(x,y_1) \leq F(x,y_2)  \text{ for } y_1\leq y_2.
\end{equation}
Assume also that for $x_1\leq x_2$ and $y_1\leq y_2$, we have

\begin{equation}
F(x_2,y_2)-F(x_2,y_1)-F(x_1,y_2)+F(x_1,y_1)\geq 0.
\end{equation}
Define $p((x_1,x_2] \times(y_1,y_2])=F(x_2,y_2)-F(x_2,y_1)-F(x_1,y_2)+F(x_1,y_1).$ Prove that $p$ satisfy countably additive properties (i.e. $p(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n,b_n] \times (c_n,d_n])= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p((a_n,b_n] \times (c_n,d_n])$).

Comment: Countable additive.. among only the sets of the form $(x_1,x_2]\times(y_1,y_2]$, or how is it meant?

Comment: I mean $p(\cup (a_i,b_i] \times (c_i,d_i]) = \sum p ((a_i,b_i] \times (c_i,d_i])$